# Redis - Hits count tracking and querying in given datetime range

Tags: c#, java, python, ruby, redis

I have many different items and I want to keep a track of number of hits to each item and then query the hit count for each item in a given datetime range, down to every second.

So i started storing the hits in a sorted set, one sorted set for each second (unix epoch time) for example :

```
zincrby ItemCount:1346742000 item1 1    
zincrby ItemCount:1346742000 item2 1
zincrby ItemCount:1346742001 item1 1
zincrby ItemCount:1346742005 item9 1
```

Now to get an aggregate hit count for each item in a given date range :

```
1. Given a start datetime and end datetime:
   Calculate the range of epochs that fall under that range.

2. Generate the key names for each sorted set using the epoch values example:
   ItemCount:1346742001, ItemCount:1346742002, ItemCount:1346742003

3. Use Union store to aggregate all the values from different sorted sets 

   ZUINIONSTORE _item_count KEYS....

4. To get the final results out:

   ZRANGE _item_count 0, -1 withscores
```

So it kinda works, but i run into problem when I have a big date range like 1 month, the number of key names calculated from step 1 & 2 run into millions (86400 epoch values per day).
With such large number of keys, ZUINIONSTORE command fails - the socket gets broken. Plus it takes a while to loop through and generate that many keys.

How can i design this in Redis in a more efficient way and still keep the tracking granularity all the way down to seconds and not minutes or days.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you should avoid big unions of sorted sets. a nice trick you can do, assuming you know the maximum hits an item can get per second.

1. sorted set per item with timestamps as BOTH scores and values.
2. but the scores are incremented by 1/(max_predicted_hits_per_second), if you are not the first client to write them. this way the number after the decimal dot is always hits/max_predicted_hits_per second, but you can still do range queries.

so let's say max_predicted_hits_per_second is 1000. what we do is this (python example):

```
#1. make sure only one client adds the actual timestamp, 
#by doing SETNX to a temporary key)

now = int(time.time())
rc = redis.setnx('item_ts:%s' % itemId, now)


#just the count part
val = float(1)/1000
if rc: #we are the first to incement this second
   val += now
   redis.expire('item_ts:%s' % itemId, 10) #we won't need that anymore soon, assuming all clients have the same clock

#2 increment the count
redis.zincrby('item_counts:%s' % itemId, now, amount = val)
```

and now querying a range will be something like:

```
counts = redis.zrangebyscore('item_counts:%s' % itemId, minTime, maxTime + 0.999, withscores=True)

total = 0
for value, score in counts:
    count = (score - int(value))*1000
    total += count
```

Comment: I dont know the maximum hits, there is no cap to it. Also how will you know what all keys to run zrangebyscore on ? not all items will have hits in a given time period.

Comment: a. you can assume something huge - 1 million? 10 million? per item! you have double precision, it doesn't matter.  b. your question as I read it was about counting per item, my bad. what you can do is another set that is global, with itemId:timestamp as value and the timestamp as score. that way you can get the items for a time range, and query each. it's ugly but it will work. but this approach might not be ideal for what you want, but probably more efficient than what you've described. there are a few others, I might have time to share some thoughts later.

Comment: Yeah making multiple requests seems ugly, ideally i want to wrap all commands in a MULTI/EXEC and get back the results. Maybe Lua scripting can help in redis 2.6 but for now i'm looking for a non-scripted solution. the other issue with fetching a list of items first and then querying on those items is that if the item list is really long then you are back to the original problem where i'm getting my socket broken 'cuz of really huge command list. admittedly  item list will be much smaller but you never know.